# $X=[0,1]\cup \mathbb{N}$ with topology $\tau^{*}=\tau \cup\{[0, 1] \cup \mathbf{A}: \mathbf{A} \subseteq \mathbb{N}\}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

let $\tau$  be euclidean topology on  $[0,1]$  and $X=[0,1]\cup \mathbb{N}$ with following  topology: $$\tau^{*}=\tau \cup\{[0, 1] \cup \mathbf{A}: \mathbf{A} \subseteq \mathbb{N}\}$$

now which of following options is **NOT** true ?

1- $(X,\tau^{*})$ is Hausdorff.

2-$\tau^{*}$ and $\tau$ are topological equivalent on  $[0,1]$ .

3- $[0,1]$ is compact in $(X,\tau^{*})$.

4- $[0,1]$ is dense in $(X,\tau^{*})$.

i think "1" is not true because every open neighborhood of numbers 3 and 2 have non empty intersection .

Comment: You’re right I think.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma .so if 3 be true then 4 is false .

Comment: 3 and 4 are both clearly true ( one line proofs).

Comment: @HennoBrandsma .if $[0,1]$ be compact so this is close so closure of [0,1] is itself and [0,1] is not dense.

Comment: A compact set is closed in a Hausdorff space. Which this is not as we saw.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma why $[0,1]$ is dense in $(X,\tau^{*})$ ?

Comment: Every open set intersects it.

Comment: @1200785626 If $[0,1]$ were closed, its complement $\{2,3,4\cdots\}$ will be open, which obviously isn't since every non-empty open intersects $[0,1]$.